# Wie sagt man einen Satz höflicher?

Tags: politeness

Ich schicke eine E-Mail an eine offizielle Institution und der folgende Satz erscheint mir etwas unhöflich. Wie kann ich diesen Satz höflicher machen?

> Dieser Termin ist für zwei Personen (ich und mein Ehemann), verstehe ich das richtig?

Mir wurde ein Termin zugeteilt, aber dieser Termin muss für zwei Personen sein. Wie kann ich höflich um Bestätigung bitten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Höflichkeit ergibt sich teils auch aus dem Kontext wie man einen solchen Satz einbettet in vorhergehende oder folgende Sätze. Ansich ist der Satz nicht unhöflich (aber auch nicht ausgesprochen höflich) sondern in seiner Wirkung durch den Kontext bestimmt. Allerdings hat die Formulierung "verstehe ich das richtig" häufiger (aber auch nicht immer) einen Unterton von Unglauben und / oder (negativer) Überraschung, der hier vielleicht nicht angebracht ist.

Andere Möglichkeiten das Gleiche oder Ähnliches auszudrücken könnten sein:

> Um Missverständnissen vorzubeugen: dieser Termin ist für uns beide, meinen Ehemann und mich?

> Können Sie bestätigen, dass der Termin für meinen Ehemann und mich gemeinsam gilt?

> Gehe ich richtig in der Annahme, dass der Termin für meinen Ehemann und mich gemeinsam ist?

Comment: Unsere Gedanken zu "verstehe ich das richtig" sind genau die gleichen. Vielen Dank, dass Sie mich so klar verstanden haben und für Ihre Antworten!

Comment: Was diese Antwort nicht erwähnt und trotzdem schön umsetzt in den Beispielen ist die Umkehrung der Personen. Wenn man mehrere Personen erwähnt, und man selber in dieser Liste ist, dann ist es immer am höflichsten sich selbst zuletzt zu erwähnen ("Mich und meinen Ehemann" -> "Meinen Ehemann und mich").